# Why is the plural of "number one" "number ones" and not "numbers one"?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

There are two imaginable plurals of *number one*:

- *number**s** one*
- *number one**s***

The resources I found on internet say that *number one**s*** is the correct plural.

Why is it so? Is there a more general rule from which this is deductible? I would understand it if the first noun (*number*) would have a function of an adjective, such as in *race car*. However here the first noun sounds to me as the main noun, with *one* as a kind of an adjective. Hence I would feel more logical to pluralize *number* rather than *one*.

As @CarlWitthoft noted in his answer, what confuses me is that as the software programmer I feel very natural to use sentences like "the table contains three numbers one", "the string contains three characters/digits one".

For me as a mathematician and software programmer *one* is clearly a kind of a *type of a number*, not the opposite. So I don't think this question is primarily about "pluralizing noun phrases", but rather about what is the head of the noun phrase *number one*.

Comment: The head of the noun phrase *number one* is *one*. A "number one" (if not treated as a Star Trek rank etc) isn't a type of number or type of one, but if one must make a choice, it is closer to a type of *one*, as distinguished from, say, the "character one", the "string one", or the "word one". So we pluralise *one* (the head of the noun phrase) instead of *number*.

Comment: @Lawrence: for me as a mathematician and software programmer *one* is clearly a type of a *number*, not the opposite. So I don't think this question is primarily about "pluralizing noun phrases", but rather about *what* is the head of the noun phrase *number one*, so hence it is not a duplicate of the question mentioned by you.

Comment: Also a programmer, but "_the table contains three numbers one_" sounds completely wrong (for, say, `1, 2, 1, 3, 1`). I _might_ say "_the table contains three number ones_", but would be more likely to use "_the table contains three instances [or copies] of  the number one_".

Comment: @Honza I've also done CS research back in the day and still keep my hand in programming, so I understand where you're coming from. My previous comment was trying to do just what your comment mentioned - justify why I think 'one' is the head of this noun phrase. Primarily, it is that 'number' modifies 'one, not he other way around. Out of all the types that 'one' could be (string, number, char, 'bool', etc), it's a 'number' type of 'one'. The important thing is that it is a 'one'. Eg "contains 3 numbers 1" isn't idiomatic in English; "contains 3 instances of number 1" would be better.

Comment: @Lawrence: So I take it that **in English** the *one* in *number one* is of the type *number*. In my language (Czech) it is the other way and that's why I have the problem to feel it in English - we pluralize *number**s** one* in Czech (but we can also form a single word with the meaning of *number one* using just a proper ending :) and then pluralize the word).

Comment: @HonzaZidek I think you have identified the central issue. In English, *number* acts like an adjective (or *noun modifier*) for *one*. *One* doesn't modify *number*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Collins article](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/number-one) (the one at Wiktionary is also well worth looking at, though many correctly consider Collins the more authoritative reference) gives different senses for the term 'number one', indicating that it is either an open compound or a close-bound collocation. These usually pluralise by the affixation of the second orthographic word

(a couple of power showers; some ink wells; two steel bridges).

This is because typically, compounds in English are endocentric – that is, one of the elements is the head of the construction. And that is typically the right-hand element. Power showers are types of showers;  'steel bridge' is [a] bridge made of steel (not steel considered suitable for building bridges).

Though 'number one' is certainly not endocentric when used as an idiom (and probably best not analysed as endocentric when used mathematically*), it seems that the pull of the tendency to add the affix to the right-hand orthographic word wins out on pluralising. *In fact, as 'one' and 'number one' are synonyms ('I'll have three number ones, and five sevens –  the brass, not the silver'), unlike 'number' and 'number one', if one insisted on identifying a head, it would be 'one' here.

I'll add that there is an unusual feature to this specific example. Few compound nouns / close-bound collocations are [noun + numeral] in form, and of those that are

(cloud nine, Famous Five, Chicago Seven, Number Six, Birmingham Six ...)

most are too fixed/specific to accept pluralisation. And in any case, 'Five', 'Seven' ... should probably be regarded as nouns rather than numerals (though I'd regard 'cloud nine', 'Famous Five' ... each as a single lexeme) here. 'Chiltern Hundreds' is a rare plurale tantum hereabouts. And 'blues and twos' is very informal.

Comment: Exactly: *Power showers* are types of showers; *steel bridge* is a bridge made of steel! But "number one" is **not** a *type of one*, it is a type of a number!

Comment: No; 'number one' is an idiom, a single lexeme, when used in the non-mathematical way: not a type of number but defined as a person / organisation (CED) / thing (ODO). But its plural patterns on similar open compounds whose origins are more easily seen. / Referring to the symbol, << number sevens >> etc pattern on << letter _g_'s >>. [This authority](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofadx9Sb6BM) is certainly not as convincing as but doubtless better known than CGEL etc.

Comment: As @CarlWitthoft noted in his answer, what confuses me is that as the software programmer I feel very natural to use sentences like "the table contains three numbers one", "the string contains three characters/digits one".

Comment: I'm a retired maths teacher and am totally unfamiliar with the 'three numbers one' phrase. I _am_ familiar with '1010 acid', a nickname used in the antioxidant trade, but would consider it too niche a usage for ELU. // Looking on Google, there are quite a few relevant hits for "three number ones", but I haven't been able to find a single one among the many examples a search for "three numbers one" turns up. (You could trawl further through these.)  I've got to consider the latter non-standard, though it may be used in computing registers.

Comment: I am not a native speaker so I may be used to something completely wrong. Would you say "three character Z's" or "three characters Z"?

Comment: 'Three zeds' (or, if needed, 'three letter zeds'). In the US, they use 'zee'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought you East-side-of-the-pond-ers used "zed" for "zero" ?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft Have you checked in say OED, ODO, CED or Collins?

Comment: Saying "three numbers one" is like saying "three see one" or "three hit one", it implies that there is a "two" and unnecessarily but practically also a "three" and subsequent ones.  So "three agree this person is the first one", then assuming that more Judges are not added or taken away the "three numbers the second, two", then the "three numbers third", etc. The plural "numbers" referring to the plurality of the numbering (enumeration) and not of the one. The word "number" being pre-tense, "numbers" or "numbering" being present tense, and "numbered" being past tense.

Answer (score -1):

Replace "one" with something easier to parse.

"His poker hand had 3 Aces."  (not  threes Ace)  It's clumsy at best to precede a specified numeral (1, 2, or whatever) with the word "number" .

I will note for the software-aware crowd here that one might distinguish between numeric and character values by citing "all the numbers 1"   vs.  "all the characters '1' " in a code file.

Comment: And that's exactly what confuses me - as a member the "software-aware crowd" I feel perfectly familiar with the phrase "all the numbers 1".